# How to read CSV Vertically instead of horizontally in Terraform using csvdecode?

Tags: csv, terraform

I am able to read the CSV vertically when my CSV is like below

```
name,email,age
TOM,tom@email.com,13
BOB,bob@email.com,14
ANN,ann@email.com,15
```

But now would like to read the CSV horizontally to avoid large configurations in CSV

```
name,TOM,BOB,ANN
email,tom@email.com,bob@email.com,ann@email.com
age,13,14,15
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

You could develop [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data-sources)  in terraform.

The external resource would read your CSV file, parse it based on your requirements, and return to tf for further use.

In the link I provided there is an example of how you can develop an external data source.